# Limit object sharing of virtual base classes in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, modeling, virtual-inheritance

I know about physical and virtual inheritance in C++. However, I would like to know if this model could somehow be achieved by any design patterns or tricks.

The classes E and F and the bases of those should not be modified.. Imagine that they come from an extern library.

Everything below E and F is open. It would be ok to introduce intermediate helping classes, non-member function, templates... everything that would realize this:

```
           BaseClass
           /       \
          /         \
         A           A
        / \         / \
       /   \       /   \
      B     C     B     D
       \   /       \   /
        \ /         \ /
         E           F
          \         /
           \       /
            \     /
           FinalClass
```

Note that E and F shall not share an A. FinalClass should indeed contain 2 A.
My problem is, that the creation of E or F would require, that B, C and D inherit A virtually.. however, if A is a virtual base class, then the compiler would only create one A object in FinalClass instead of two different ones.

So, I think many of you would recommend composition instead of inheritance here. However, composition modells a "has a"-relationship here and not an "is a"-relationship.
In explaination, I would like FinalClass to truly behave like an E or F, including being able to convert it to those classes.

Comment: Can you make `A` a class template?

Comment: Let's assume I can. What would it change? Class B also would have to decide, which specialization of A it would like to inherit.

Comment: If you can change your classes names (template is just a way to change class names), you can solve your constraints `template <class T> class B<T> : public virtual A<T> {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This layout is not feasible in C++, even with additional helping class.

The fact that that B inherits from A, and you want to share the A inheritance with C on one side and with D on the other, requires B, C and D to virtually inherit from A.  But then A would be shared accross both branches of your diamond.

## Alternatives

What alternatives could there be ?

- If you'd manage to break the sharing of A between the left and right branches of your diamonds, you would also break the sharing of the common base.
- If you'd introduce some intermediary classes A1, A2 for implementing the left and right share in your branches, you'd but stuck by the fact that both B have to inherit either the one or the other
- The only way out could be to have a duplicate class for B.

This last solution doesn't fulfill your requirement but would look as follows:

```
struct Base { int x; };
struct A : public virtual Base { int a; };
struct AC : public A{};  // synonym 
struct B : public virtual A { int b; };
struct BC : public virtual AC { int b;  }; // !! clone !! 
struct C : public virtual AC { int c; };
struct D : public virtual A { int d; };
struct E : public BC, C { int e; };
struct F : public B, D { int f; };
struct Final : public E, F { };
```

And here the access to the memebers:

```
Final f;
f.x = 2;    // unambiguous:  there's onely one of it 
f.f = 1; 
f.e = 2; 
f.d = 3; 
f.c = 4; 
//f.b = 5;   // ambiguous:  there are two of it 
f.E::b = 5;  // successful desambiguation
f.F::b = 6;  // successfuldesambiguation
//f.a = 7;   // ambiguous:  there are two of it
f.E::a = 7;  // successful desambiguation
f.F::a = 8;  // successful desambiguation
```

To come back to your problem statement:  you say you can't intervene above E and F.  In this case your options are very limited :

- you publicly inherit
- you privately inherit via some intermediary classes

But the effect would be the same on sharing, as following code desmonstrates (on the top of the above one) :

```
class FI : private F  // make F private
{ public: 
    void set_xa(int u, int v) { x = u; a= v; }
    void show_xa() { cout << "x:" << x << " a:" << a << endl; }
};
class EI : private E  // make E private
{
public:
    void set_xa(int u, int v) { x = u; a = v; }
    void show_xa() { cout << "x:" << x << " a:" << a << endl; }
};

struct Final3 : public EI, public FI { }; 

Final3 h;
h.EI::set_xa(3, 4);
h.FI::set_xa(5, 6);
h.EI::show_xa(); 
h.FI::show_xa();
// the shared virtually inherited memebers are still shared !
```

## Conclusion:

With inheritance, you're completely bound by the design above E and F that you aren't allowed to influence.

So the first questions would be:

- can't you alter this design after all (i.e. cloning of one B) ?
- wouldn't it be unacceptable of having A shered between both branches (may be there's are valid reason after all) ?

If you answer is no to both questions, you'll have to go for composition, and implement a kind of **[proxy design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html)**, where your composed object is a proxy for your both components.

Comment: If A is not virtual, how would B and C or B and D share one A?

Comment: @JackSabbath - fully right, sorry: I've read the question to fast and didn't notice the two common B.  I've made a comprehensive edit.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I actually asked this, because I am the author of a library and so I wanted to figure out if this design pattern would be a dead end before implementing it. I think my model could be realized, if E derives physically from A, while B and C will not derive from A, but instead use curious recurring template pattern to access the A, which E inherited. Same for the other side of the diagram. Of course, the B's wouldn't have the same type (CRTP specialization). They'd need an interface base class. I'll better forget this pattern all along.